# MySQL - Can't Convert From MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Trying To convert This MSSQL 2012R2 Statement into MySQL 5.7

```
SELECT SUM(Cost + Credit_Amount) As Daily_Cost FROM Google_Costing
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE() -2), 0) AND     
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE() -2) + 1, 0)
```

I have tried replacing `DATEADD` with `DATE_ADD` and `DATEDIFF` with `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, but still no luck. Any help is appreciated.

I get the error:

> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

So I change the statement to:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost + Credit_Amount) As Daily_Cost FROM Google_Costing
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE() -2), 0) AND 
DATE_ADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE() -2) + 1, 0)
```

This time I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE() -2), 0) AND DATE_ADD(MONTH,
>   TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONT' at line 2

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: Do you have a column name `MONTH`? If so, try enclosing it in square brackets `[MONTH]` or ticks. I recommend not using reserved words for column names...

Comment: Also, see the `DATE_ADD` reference for correct usage: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: No column named month, when you use MSSQL, DATEADD allows first position to define interval, in this case, MONTH. I'll check the MSQL Reference to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: What result you are expecting from this query?

Comment: What logic has to be used in `WHERE` condition? Do you have function in the name of `GETDATE()`?

Comment: It's supposed to return all records and sum the Cost and Credit Fields from the first day of the month to the current day of the month minus 2 days, so to use today as an example I would expect it to return all records between the dates 10/1/2016 to 10/22/2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out these biscuits...

```
SELECT SUM(Cost + Credit_Amount) As Daily_Cost FROM Google_Costing
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') 
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
```

Comment: That worked exactly as planned! Thank you so much for the help!